# How do I add Facebook and Twitter share buttons to a group of existing articles in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, web

Am I going to have to do it individually or is there some way I can alter the template or wrapper or whatever to add buttons to all articles at once?

Comment: No. Yes.  What have you tried? Can you write a better version of this question? Otherwise those are the answers but as a bonus I'll tell you the information is on the Joomla docs site as well as most of the related questions that show up with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extension. It will show social buttons to all your articles. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/bt-social-sharing

Comment: Thank you, hive mind representative, you have been very helpful :)